# How to draw a dynamic graph?

Tags: android, database, graph

I have to draw a dynamic graph of data from a database in android

Any example code regarding this will be appreciated.

Comment: which type of graph?like pie chart.

Answer (score 1):

I like GraphViz for generating graphs as .gif files.

Answer (score 0):

So...many...graph questions...

Read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156740/im-looking-for-fancy-charts-library-for-android/5157576#5157576

TeeChart beta is public: http://steema.com/entry/60

Can heavily recommend TeeChart, it's a great library. Been using it for a while now. Since I haven't put this anywhere yet, here's a bit of my "how-to" document:

```
TeeChart info:

Disable 3D:            chart.getAspect().setView3D(false);
Disable Legend:        chart.getLegend().setVisible(false);
Disable footer:     chart.getFooter().setVisible(false);
Disable header:     chart.getHeader().setVisible(false);

SOLVED - How to set marks to data value instead of cylinder number?
    For a Bar data-set: bar.getMarks().setStyle(MarksStyle.VALUE);

SOLVED - How to move the marks closer to the chart rectangle?
    bar.getMarks().setArrowLength(5); - or negative values to put them on top of the bar

SOLVED - Different styles:
    bar.setBarStyle(BarStyle.RECTANGLE);

SOLVED - How do I put a heavier color reference (in terms of readability) on the legend? Thicker (higher) line, not wider
    chart.getLegend().setColorWidth(100); makes it wider, but not thicker or anything
    chart.getLegend().setFontSeriesColor(true); helps with the issue by also coloring the text
    line.getLinePen().setWidth(5); works, but it will change the width of the line as well.
    No legend callback yet.


SOLVED - How do I make the lines thicker in a graph?
    line.getLinePen().setWidth(5); works, but it will change the width of the Legend as well.

SOLVED - How do I change the color of labels on axes?
        chart.getAxes().getLeft().getLabels().getFont().setColor(Color.WHITE);
        chart.getAxes().getBottom().getLabels().getFont().setColor(Color.WHITE);


SOLVED WORKAROUND - How do I set the background color of the chart itself? Tried so far (the TChart methods that take a Color from the TChart Color class, not the View methods) - only managed to make the 'surrounding' area black.
        chart.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        chart.getCanvas().setBackColor(Color.BLACK);
        chart.getGraphics3D().setBackColor(Color.BLACK);
            ---> WORKAROUND: Use the setBackground above, then use: chart.getWalls().getBack().setVisible(false); --- setColor() on walls is bugged?


SOLVED - How to choose the bounds of a chart manually?
    chart.getAxes().getLeft().setAutomatic(false);
    chart.getAxes().getLeft().setMinMax(-2, 2);
```